# How to solve "Time Limit Exceeded" error?

Tags: c

****I am recently practicing on codeforces.com, I solved a problem there:****

Kristina has two arrays a and b, each containing n non-negative integers. She can perform the following operation on array a any number of times:

apply a decrement to each non-zero element of the array, that is, replace the value of each element ai such that ai>0 with the value ai−1 (1≤i≤n). If ai was 0, its value does not change.
Determine whether Kristina can get an array b from an array a in some number of operations (probably zero). In other words, can she make ai=bi after some number of operations for each 1≤i≤n?

For example, let n=4, a=[3,5,4,1] and b=[1,3,2,0]. In this case, she can apply the operation twice:

after the first application of the operation she gets a=[2,4,3,0];
after the second use of the operation she gets a=[1,3,2,0].
Thus, in two operations, she can get an array b from an array a.

Input
The first line of the input contains an integer t (1≤t≤104) —the number of test cases in the test.

The descriptions of the test cases follow.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer n (1≤n≤5⋅104).

The second line of each test case contains exactly n non-negative integers a1,a2,…,an (0≤ai≤109).

The third line of each test case contains exactly n non-negative integers b1,b2,…,bn (0≤bi≤109).

It is guaranteed that the sum of n values over all test cases in the test does not exceed 2⋅105.

Output
For each test case, output on a separate line:

YES, if by doing some number of operations it is possible to get an array b from an array a;
NO otherwise.
You can output YES and NO in any case (for example, strings yEs, yes, Yes and YES will be recognized as a positive response).

**here is my solution**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void array_decrement(int arr[],int length)   
{
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {       
        if(arr[i]>0)
        {
            arr[i]--;       //decrements all element by one, if element is 0 then it won't be changed
        }
    }
}

int array_cmp(int arr1[],int arr2[],int length)
{
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<arr2[i])     //if any element will less than element of 2nd array, then it will return -1 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(arr1[i]>arr2[i])     //if any element will more than element of 2nd array, then it will return 0
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;                   // if all elements are same then it will return 1
}

int main()
{
    int t,n,cmp;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  // t = number of testcases
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr1[n]; 
        int arr2[n];

        for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr1[p]);
        }
        for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr2[p]);
        }


        // logical part
        while (i>=0)     //loop runs for infinite times, but it has a set of conditions which will break loop in finite time
        {
            if(array_cmp(arr1,arr2,n)==1)          // if all elements are same print "YES"
            {
                printf("YES\n");
                break;

            }else if(array_cmp(arr1,arr2,n)==0)    //if any element can be decremented then it will decrement
            {
                array_decrement(arr1,n);

            }else if(array_cmp(arr1,arr2,n)==-1)    // if any element gets to less than 2nd elemnet during process of decrement then print "NO"
            {
                printf("NO\n");
                break;
            }
        }     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***My Problem***:  It shows "**Time limit Exceeded**" when I went to submit this code, can anyone help me to solve this error?, ***actually I've faced this error First time.***

Comment: The idea of these puzzles isn't just to solve them: but to find an efficient way to solve them, and *that* is the real puzzle. The "beginner" puzzles are easy on the time limit as well as the task.

Comment: Why are you calling `array_cmp` three times? Call it once and store the result in a variable. And the final `else if` need not test any vlaue, as there is no altenative. Just `else` will do.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried this, but it still shows this error.

Comment: So explore your algorithms and make it better. Also as noted, repeatedly allocating and freeing memory is inefficient. You are usually told the constraints, so you know what the maximum array size will be. I see you have added that now and FWIW your use of return value is unconventional c.f. `strcmp()`.

Comment: Suppose all the array elements are near the constraint value 100000000. How efficient do you think the literal "decrement each element" is going to be? You need to find another way to analyse the data: yours is like permforming division by repeated subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am recently practicing on codeforces.com... It shows "Time limit Exceeded" when I went to submit this code.

As [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949302/how-to-solve-time-limit-exceeded-error#comment128847784_72949421):

> These types of coding challenges are designed to test time complexity of the algorithms. When you get a runtime limit exceeded, it's usually because **your algorithm is not the best way to solve the problem**.

Your algorithm compares the arrays *two* times in a loop which *actually performs* all the possible decrements.

Given **N**, the number of elements in each array (up to 5*10<sup>4</sup>, apparently), and **K**, the number of possible steps necessary to transform an array into the other (note that 0 <= a[i], b[i] <= 10<sup>9</sup>), the time complexity of the posted algorithm is O(**N** * **K**).

---

Consider the following points:

- The array `a` can be transformed into `b` (applying the rules of the problem statement) if there exits a non-negative value `k` (the number of decrements) such that, for every `i`:

  - If `b[i] == 0`, then `k >= a[i]`.
  - Otherwise:

    - If `b[i] <= a[i]`, then `k == a[i] - b[i]`.
    - Othrwise, `k` doesn't exist and the transformation cannot be done.
- We don't need to actually perform the transformation, we only have to compare the elements of the two arrays (not even all them, in some cases) to find out if such a `k` value exists. In other words, this algorithm has an O(**N**) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting your solution codeforces perform a lot of test cases on it. The error says that it takes too much time so your solution is not optimal for runtime.

After the first look at the code I can give an advise that dynamic allocation is too expensive, you must try preallocation.

Comment: Ok, so I will declare two static arrays instead of dynamic arrays, but before I submit my code, I want to Know that how do I know about run time of my program of 5x10^4 inputs before submitting program?

Comment: I tried that, but it still shows that error.

Comment: How do you know the run time in advance? By making your own set of test cases, within the full range of the problem constraints.

Comment: Dynamic allocation rarely is responsible for such performance issues. These types of coding challenges are designed to test time complexity of the algorithms. When you get a runtime limit exceeded, it's usually because your algorithm is not the best way to solve the problem.